# SD card img file copying on linux

Tags: linux, partitioning, sd-card

I am trying to make Banana PI bootable SD card.

First delete old partitions from SD, then create two new partitions and format them as vfat and ext4, as [here described](http://wiki.lemaker.org/BananaPro/Pi:Setting_up_the_bootable_SD_card)

Then copying disk image:

```
sudo dd if=Lubuntu_For_BPI_V3.1.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1M
```

And then I'm trying to check if all right, mounting first or second partition:

```
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/sdc1 /mnt/
```

or

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdc2 /mnt/
```

All these operations finish formally successfully, but after mounting I see that /mnt is empty.

What is wrong here? Maybe SD card is incompatible(Oltramax 32G)?
How to check compatiblity?